# python script to open a file in sublime text

Tags: python, xcode, sublimetext2, lldb

**Context:**

I am modifying a small python script, so that the output of a lldb command that I run from Xcode debugger, will be output to a file and open up in sublime text.

```
import lldb
import os
import subprocess

def print_to_file(debugger, command, result, dict):
  #Change the output file to a path/name of your choice
  f=open("/Users/venkat13/pcomponents.txt","w")
  debugger.SetOutputFileHandle(f,True);
  debugger.HandleCommand(command)
  path = "/Users/venkat13/pcomponents.txt"
  sublimePath = '/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app'
  subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (sublimePath, path))


def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
  debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f po.print_to_file print_to_file ')
```

**Problem :**

This above script is generating the file, but it does not open in sublime text. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because Popen will not directly pass the entire string to the shell unless you specify `shell=True` (It just seems to me that you expecting the command to work the same way you would typically type on a shell).

Instead use:

```
subprocess.Popen([sublimePath, path])
```

Alternatively, (**NOT RECOMMENDED**):

```
subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (sublimePath, path), shell=True)
```